# wso2:esb BAM Message Tracer Handler Aggregate feature is missing in esb 4.9.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 esb4.9.0 version and also wso2das3.0.0. I need to send the message tracer data to das from esb and read somewhere that BAM Message Tracer Handler Aggregate need to be used in esb to send traces but I am not able to find this feature in esb and also tried various repository links to install this feature in esb4.9 but no link has BAM Message Tracer Handler Aggregate feature.

Please provide any help on this

Comment: AFAIK this feature was in carbon 42x product. ESB 4.9.0 is a 44x based product.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would you please eloborate your response as I am newbiew to WSO2 ESB and DAS as well. How do I get  BAM Message Tracer Handler Aggregate feature in WSO2 ESb 4.9.0

Comment: Found the below link where it's mentioned that WSO2 ESB  is a 44x based. http://wso2.com/projects/carbon/provisioning-wso2-carbon-with-equinox-p2/  and corresponding link to download BAM Message Tracer Handler Aggregate  feature is http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/ . But this link does't contain the feature BAM Message Tracer Handler Aggregate